# How to recognize that Django fixtures loading is ongoing?

Tags: django, django-fixtures

I have delusions that I've seen it in some piece of code and it's some variable's state. Example usage would be in signal handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked it out yet, but from this discussion, http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8399 it seems that loaddata sends out post_save signals.

Comment: Dunno about the signals but, looks like the check for module named `loaddata` in `inspect.stack()` used there is not maybe the most efficient but works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(8 years later) stumbled upon own question, and the example would be (tested in >=1.11):

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save) # `post_save` also works
def callback_on_loaddata(sender, **kwargs):
    # 'raw' indicates that loaddata cmd was issued
    if kwargs.get('created', True) and kwargs.get('raw', False):
        # mark on-going loaddata, call kwargs.get('instance').clean() etc.
        ...
```